# Unit Tests when using uirouter angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm relatively new to ng2+, but I haven't been able to find any example about how to run unit/integration tests while using uirouter. I have a basic sanity test that looks like this:

```
describe('LoginSignupComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginSignupComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginSignupComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent,
        LoginSignupComponent,
        CreateUserComponent,
        ValidationComponent,
        WidgetLoadingComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        InputMaskModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        UIRouterModule.forRoot({})
      ],
      providers: [
        LoginService,
        LoginStateService,
        StateService,
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginSignupComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But it fails with the following: 
`Error: Can't resolve all parameters for StateService: (?).`

Where StateService is coming from uirouter. How do I fix this? I couldn't find any documentation on uirouter about this.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was enough to just reference the UI Router module in the imports section:

```
 await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({}), 
    HttpClientModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: 'environment', useValue: environment},
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that there is one parameter in the constructor of `StateService` that is not present in the current `TestBed`. Open the implementation of `StateService`, check its constructor and provide the missing dependency to the `TestBed`. If that dependency needs to be mocked or it's just not important for the test, use a fake implementation with `useValue` or `useClass` in the `providers` array.

Comment: So how come when I add `{provide: StateService, useClass: MockStateService}` to the providers array and put `@Injectable()
class MockStateService {

}` at the top of the file, I still get the same error?

Comment: Your `MockStateService` does not need an `@Injectable()` annotation. If that still does not work, something within ui-router is acting up, but I don't know that library good enough unfortunately.